# regex's laziness doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex

```
...
</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <p margin-left:35.7pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-17.85pt;line-height: normal;mso-list:l7 level1 lfo5 ">
```

Above is part of the HTML I want to refine with regex. For some reason, the HTML is messed up, as you can see there is only one double-quote inside the P tag. I'm trying to match HTML tags that contains only one double-quote, and this double-quote is followed immediately by a sharp bracket.
I use `/<[^"]+?">/`, but it match all of the above code. Of course I can use `/<[^"^>]+?">/` to match what I want to match, but I just don't understand why the first regex doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: Words to the wise, do not use regex with html/xml/etc.  Use an engine built for those formats.

Comment: `/<[^"]+?">/` will start with the first `<` (left to right) and *then* lazily match 1+ non-`"` characters. The next part of your expression is `">`, so when it first comes across this sequence it will stop lazily matching. ***It still starts with the very first `<`, since you are matching from left to right, it just will not eat up extra `">` characters.*** (Which means lazy is pointless in this scenario, since you are looking for non-`"` characters followed by `"`.)

Comment: Thanks @Sam, now I see. So besides using `/<[^"^>]+?">/`, I can try matching it from right to left. But how do I match from right to left? I found some post in stackoverflow but don't quite understand. Is there any more formal and distinguishable keywords that I can google for "matching from right to left"?

Comment: Regular expressions always match left to write. But being more specific (rather than just `<`) may help, i.e. [`/<p[^"]+">/`](http://regex101.com/r/tW1xP8/1).

Comment: Only .NET regex allows you to match from right to left. The behavior is as if you reverse the string, then match normally from left to right.